# Homogeneous ideals such that $I(V(I))=I$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If we have the following conditions: $K$ is a field not algebraically closed, $I$ is a homogeneous ideal in the polynomial ring $K[x]$, $V$ is a projective variety,and $V(I)\neq\varnothing $  then can we say $I(V(I))=I$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you considered the ideal $I$ generated by $X^2$ in $K[X]$ ? you should look at the notion of *reduced* ideals.

Comment: I mean $I$ is an ideal in  $K[x]=K[x_0,…,x_n]$ generated by Finite set of polynomials